# Read current collection throughput of Cosmos DB in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

Using the following [command in Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb/sql/database/throughput?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-sql-database-throughput-show) one can read the current throughput (RU/s) from a Cosmos DB database:

```
az cosmosdb sql database throughput show
```

Result:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "location": null,
  "name": null,
  "tags": null,
  "throughput": 400,
  "type": null
}
```

I want this value (throughput 400) in my .NET core application. Currently I reference the Nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` and I already tried this:

```
using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://MYCOSMOS.documents.azure.com:443/"), "MYKEY"))
{
    var options = new RequestOptions() 
    { 
        PopulateQuotaInfo = true 
    };
    var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("Sample", "orders");
    var result = await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(uri, options);    
}
```

But this only provides me some quotas regarding document amount and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` you are using the old v.2 SDK which has been obsoleted by the new [v3 SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3) - `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`

With the new SDK you would do something like this:

```
using (var client = new CosmosClient(new Uri("https://MYCOSMOS.documents.azure.com:443/"), "MYKEY"))
{
   var database = client.GetDatabase("Sample");
   var container = database.GetContainer("orders");

   var databaseThroughput = await database.ReadThroughputAsync();
   var containerThroughput = await container.ReadThroughputAsync();
}
```